# How to save memory when training a model in Keras where X is f(Y)?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

I have a problem where my input X can be defined as a function applied to output Y. I imagine I can save memory during training by only having Y in memory and creating X per example during training.

If this is my training code:

```
history = model.fit(
    x_train,
    y_train,
    batch_size=64,
    epochs=2,
    # We pass some validation for
    # monitoring validation loss and metrics
    # at the end of each epoch
    validation_data=(x_val, y_val),
)
```

How can I define x_train as f(y_train) per example? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could create a custom dataset from a generator using [`from_generator`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#from_generator). Something like this:

```
def create_ds(y_data):
    def generator():
        for y in y_data:
            yield f(x), y

        ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(generator=generator, output_signature=...)
        ds = ds.batch(64).prefetch(buffer_size=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
    return ds

ds = create_ds(y_train)
val_ds = create_ds(y_val)

history = model.fit(ds, epochs=2, validation_data=val_ds)
```

Comment: I believe this is the natural way of doing it but since the question was how to do it at training time to save space, I think it's doesn't answer this particular question.

Comment: Yes but it's a generator. It will not transform all y_train, but only create as much data as currently needed while training

Comment: You're answer is better I'll delete mine, thanks for the tip !